# Why is my array calling everything in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, variables

I want the array to call one random variable from it but it calls every variable in it and I don't know why. 
Code:

```
var atk1 = Billy.giveLife("self");
var atk2 = Billy.punch("self");
var attack = [atk1,atk2];
function test(){
    var r = Math.round(Math.random()*(attack.length-1));
    attack[r];
}
test();
```

Comment: Probably because you are calling the functions when you do `var atk1 = Billy.giveLife("self");` and `var atk2 = Billy.punch("self");` yourself. Those two methods are executed and their **return values** are assigned to `atk1` and `atk2`.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish with the `test()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first 2 lines you are immediately calling the functions. `attack[r]` does nothing, square braces are only for selecting an element from an array.

Here’s one solution to what you might be trying to do, using anonymous arrow functions to store your functions to be called later:

```
var atk1 = () => Billy.giveLife("self");
var atk2 = () => Billy.punch("self");
var attack = [atk1,atk2];
function test(){
    var r = Math.round(Math.random()*(attack.length-1));
    attack[r]();
}
test();
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think you are missing braces '()' so I did a little prototype for you, here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/e75nx3rn/

I modified your code a little bit to make more visual:

```
function printf(data) {
  $('#out').html($('#out').html() + '<br/>' + data);
}

var atk1 = function() {
  printf('atk1');
}
var atk2 = function() {
  printf('atk2');
}
var atk3 = function() {
  printf('atk3');
}
var atk4 = function() {
  printf('atk4');
}
var atk5 = function() {
  printf('atk5');
}

var attack = [atk1, atk2, atk3, atk4, atk5];

function test() {
  var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (attack.length - 1));
  attack[r]();
}

setInterval(function() {
  test();
}, 1500)
```